# Does a server create copies of a script to serve to different clients?

Tags: php, apache, client-server

I'd elaborate. Suppose that the following HTML form asks the visitor for their name:

```
<form action="show_name.php" method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="visitorName" placeholder="Enter your name here">
  <input type="submit" value="Go!">
</form>
```

and sends it to the php script named show_name.php. The code in the script is:

```
<?php
    $visitorName = $_POST['visitorName'];
    echo $visitorName;
?>
```

Now there is only one script residing at the server, but the script echoes different names when different user fill the form. Is the server creating different copies of the script depending upon the request from different clients? What is this behavior called, and how can I learn more about it?

Comment: the show_name.php file is a program.  When the client sends the form data to the the program the web server runs it with the data sent from the form and returns the output to the web browser. As such there is only one program but depending on the inputs can produce a multitude of outputs

Comment: @Orangepill, but the variable seems to be storing different data every time. Is it all controlled by the server?